# Typescript - function should return a string instead of () -> string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to add the following code to detect browsers, but the error I get for `browserData` is:

```
Type '{ browserName: () => string; browserVersion: string | null; operatingSystem: string | (() => string); } | { browserName: string; browserVersion: string; operatingSystem: string; }' is not assignable to type 'BrowserData'.
Type '{ browserName: () => string; browserVersion: string | null; operatingSystem: string | (() => string); }' is not assignable to type 'BrowserData'.
Types of property 'browserName' are incompatible.
Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

```
function getBrowserInfo(): BrowserData {
  const browserInfo = detectBrowser.detect();
  const browserData: BrowserData =
    browserInfo !== null
      ? {
          browserName: browserInfo.name.toString,
          browserVersion: browserInfo.version,
          operatingSystem:
            browserInfo.os !== null ? browserInfo.os.toString : '',
        }
      : { browserName: '', browserVersion: '', operatingSystem: '' };
  return browserData;
}

declare type BrowserData = {
  browserName: string;
  browserVersion: string;
  operatingSystem: string;
};
```

I see that there is an error because the return value should be a string, but not a function that returns a string. How can I correct this?

Comment: `browserInfo.name.toString()` You didn't invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `toString` methods - otherwise,  you're making `browserName` and possible `operatingSystem` a function:

```
function getBrowserInfo(): BrowserData {
  const browserInfo = detectBrowser.detect();
  const browserData: BrowserData =
    browserInfo !== null ?
    {
      browserName: browserInfo.name.toString(),
      browserVersion: browserInfo.version,
      operatingSystem: browserInfo.os !== null ? browserInfo.os.toString() : '',
    } :
    {
      browserName: '',
      browserVersion: '',
      operatingSystem: ''
    };
  return browserData;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was totally it. Thank you